# Exception when adding a PdfFormField to a big PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I am adding a PdfTextFormField over a Table cell using a custom renderer, as per the iText7 example code in `CreateFormInTable.java`. This works initially, until I create a Table on page 3 or later of the PDF, at which point I'm getting an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.get(PdfDictionary.java:552)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDictionary.getAsArray(PdfDictionary.java:156)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage.getAnnotations(PdfPage.java:746)
at ...pdf.annot.PdfAnnotation.getPage(PdfAnnotation.java:435)
at ...forms.fields.PdfFormField.regenerateField(PdfFormField.java:1761)
at ...forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:1038)
at ...forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:999)
at ...forms.fields.PdfFormField.setValue(PdfFormField.java:994)
etc.
```

It seems fairly easy to reproduce, and I can provide a full code sample if you want, but a simple way to see the problem is to insert:

```
for (int i=1; i < 2; i++)  // Change 2 to 3 and you get an NPE
{
    Paragraph  para = new Paragraph("Page "+ i);
    doc.add( para );
    doc.add( new AreaBreak( AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE ) );
}
```

straight after the Document constructor in the aforementioned iText7 Java sample file at:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-create-fields-table#2350-createformintable.java

I've tested it on 7.0.1 and 7.0.2, with same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, currently some of the form-related functionality requires the whole PDF document structure to be in memory to operate. This means that no object can be flushed. But layout's `DocumentRenderer` flushes the pages when possible. The problem reproduces only for three or more pages because there is a small "window" of unflushed pages.

This is indeed not mentioned in the sample and can be improved in the future. In the current version, to get the desired PDF, you can set the `Document` to operate in "postpone flushing" mode using the following constructor:

```
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4, false);
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be the default behavior of the library? Shouldn't it work without setting FALSE, and FALSE be the default value?

Comment: @mixtou Don't think so. 95% of the use cases that I know of do not need advanced functionality of not flushing the content.